# How to call stored procedure to auto-increment in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: stored-procedures, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to auto-increment my `employeeNumber` by 001, 002 etc. For that I have created a stored procedure in SQL Server. I want to call that stored procedure in my ASP.NET Core Web API. I am using Entity Framework and code-first approach.

NOTE: if there are any mistakes please forgive this is my first time using Stack Overflow

```
SELECT TOP (1000) 
    [employeeID],
    [employeeName],
    [employeeAddress],
    [gender],
    [number],
    [employeeNumber]
FROM 
    [EmployeeListDB].[dbo].[Employees]

EXEC GenerateEmployeeNumber2
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GenerateEmployeeNumber2]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NextEmployeeNumber VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE @MaxEmployeeNumber INT;

    SELECT @MaxEmployeeNumber = MAX(CAST(employeeNumber AS INT)) 
    FROM Employees

    IF @MaxEmployeeNumber IS NULL 
       SET @NextEmployeeNumber = '001'
    ELSE
       SET @NextEmployeeNumber = RIGHT('000' + CAST(@MaxEmployeeNumber + 1 AS varchar(10)), 3)

     SELECT @NextEmployeeNumber AS NewEmployeeNumber
END
```

In ASP.NET Core Web API, I created a repository and a controller class for this

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace EmployeeList.Modals
{
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int employeeID { get; set; }

        public string? employeeNumber { get; set; }
        public string? employeeName { get; set; }
        public string? employeeAddress { get; set; }
        public string? gender { get; set; }
        public string? number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My `dbContext`:

```
using EmployeeList.Modals;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace EmployeeList.Data
{
    public class EmployeeListContext : DbContext
    {
        public EmployeeListContext(DbContextOptions<EmployeeListContext> options): base(options) 
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My repository:

```
using EmployeeList.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader;

namespace EmployeeList.Repository
{
    public class EmployeeNumberRepository
    {
        private readonly EmployeeListContext _Context;

        public EmployeeNumberRepository(EmployeeListContext Context)
        {
            _Context = Context;
        }

        public async Task<string> GnenerateNextEmployeeNumber()
        {
            var nextEmployeeNumber = await _Context.Employees.FromSqlRaw("EXEC GenerateEmployeeNumber2")
               .Select(e => e.employeeNumber)
               .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            return nextEmployeeNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
namespace EmployeeList.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    public class EmployeeNumberController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly EmployeeNumberRepository _Repo;

        public EmployeeNumberController(EmployeeNumberRepository Repo)
        {
            _Repo= Repo;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GnenerateNextEmployeeNumber")]

        public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GnenerateNextEmployeeNumber()
        {
            var nextEmployeeNumber = await _Repo.GnenerateNextEmployeeNumber();
            return Ok(nextEmployeeNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

In my swagger or postman, I get an http 500 error - I want value 001 (which I will put on my frontend). In my repository when I added debugger, I get value of var nextEmployeeNumber as null

Comment: My advice: Don't make numbers like `001`, `002` etc. Just use 1, 2, 3 and format how you display things. Also, what happens when employee number 1000 starts?

Comment: Also: ***DO NOT*** handle this in the API - let the database do the work! With this `SELECT MAX(ID)+1` approach, you ***WILL*** definitely run into duplicates being returned- just don't do it. Use a `SEQUENCE` or an `INT IDENTITY` column in SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you want a auto-incrementing value, use a Sequence. You can make on in EF by putting this in the OnModelCreating in your DBcontext class (where you assign your entities) if you want to call it from your EF code.

```
builder.HasSequence("MyNameForTheSequence", s => s.StartsAt(1).IncrementsBy(1));
```

You call it like this

```
return _context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR MyNameForTheSequence");
```

Calling a sproc is easy:

```
this.Database.SqlQuery<YourEntityType>("MyNameForTheStoredProc",params);
```